# Why my UV scale is not exported correctly when using an object as triplanar projector reference?

Tags: uv

I am modeling a house.
The UV texturing is, as you can see in the shader, generated by using a cube as mapping vector.
Everything looks good and correct in Blender: when I scale the cube, the texture is scaled accordingly.

But when I export the model in FBX for Unreal Engine 5, it seems that the scale of the cube gets completely lost.
You can see I also tried by modifying the scale in the MAPPING node to 2, but this seems to have no effect as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Material setups are usually bound to a render engine. You'll need to bake the texture before using it in UE5.

Comment: @JachymMichal mhhh I don't think this is the case. The texture orientation is being exported correctly, only the scale is not exported. This is possibly a bug in the exporter, in my opinion. But before submitting a bug report, I want to see if somebody knows better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exporting can only bind UV data to vertices,
The shader editor works on pixels/fragments (not UV). There is no builtin adequate equivalence between the 2. The closest thing you'll have is baking.

If you want to project UVs (and not texture coordinates) you should use one of the modifiers for UV data, or do it manually with <kbd>U</kbd>->`Project from View`

Comment: Darn it, this is bad... is there a way to have the same workflow, with a reference object to project triplanar UVs, but that get applied to the UV set?
Project from view is not good as well, as it's not triplanar.

Comment: Triplanar mapping is not equivalent to UV. In triplanar mapping, each point samples the texture in 3 different coordinates. This can't be encoded in UV

You must either bake or use triplanar mapping shaders in the target engine